# print out to 7" screen and then clear monitor using textwrapper + console login

Tags: python, text, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project/installation that will be run on a 7" monitor. At the moment the project selects a sentence from a txt file and then prints it out to using a typewriter effect. Using textwrapper the sentence will split over as many lines needed.

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *
import nltk.data
import random
import sys
import textwrap



# Access and authorize our Twitter credentials from credentials.py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


# Open text file newMaster.txt for reading
my_file = open('newMaster.txt', 'r')

text = my_file.read()

# close the file
my_file.close()

#Loop 
while True:

    #ntlk tokenizer
    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

    #my code takes text file
    forTweet = text  

    #breaks into sentences 
    tok = tokenizer.tokenize(forTweet) 

    #selects random sentence 
    newTok = random.choice(tok) 

    #makes sure sentence is less than 280 characters 
    newTok = random.choice([x for x in tok if len(x)<280])

    #text wrap to make sure words do not split on 
    str2 = textwrap.fill(newTok, 128)

    #Gets length of newTOk  
    lenghtnewTok = len(newTok) 

    #Keeps text on screen for 5 seoncds 
    sleep(5)

    # initialise clearing screen  
    stdscr = curses.initscr()  
    # Clear the screen
    stdscr.clear()  
    #keep screen clear for 2 seconds
    sleep(2)

    #This is typewrite effect 
    words = str2.replace('\n', '\r\n')
    for char in words:
        sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

However, what I would now like to acheive is that instead of printing 1 sentence, the script will:

1.select one sentence, print using typewriter effect.

1. Wait two seconds, skip a line and then print another sentence.
2. Keep doing this until it reaches bottom of screen and then clear all sentences and start again from the top.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please provide sufficient code sample (`text` and `textwrap`are not defined). Also why is there `;` at the end of line `tok = tokenizer.tokenize(forTweet);`?

Comment: Hey @Alderven, just updated/corrected code.